# How do I access Itunes U Course Manager if my country isn’t supported?

Tags: apple-id, proxy, itunes-u

I want to create a course but where I come from Itunes U Course Manager isn’t supported. I tried solving this but with no success. I use Chrome and have downloaded an extension called Bitternet which sets up a Proxy so that my IP appears to be in the US. I have also created a new apple ID which has an adress in the US but still when i try to log into the Itunes U Course Manager it says “Country not supported”.
Is there a way to bypass this?

Answer (score 1):

Use a VPN.

You can use a service like [TunnelBear](https://www.tunnelbear.com/) (not affiliated) so that you can appear to be using the service from another country.

If you have a "friend" in the country of question, you can set up your own VPN ([OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/downloads.html)) between your and their locations.  This is obviously a DIY solution and you would need the requisite skills.

Comment: I will try it but how would it make a difference if i’m already using a chrome extension Betternet which makes my IP look like its from the US?

Comment: iTunes is *not* Chrome nor does iTunes traffic go through Chrome.  Your web browsing may look like it's from the US but your iTunes traffic says otherwise.  A VPN will move *all* your traffic to the US.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the 2  ways to solve this problem with success.

1. Download a GPS faker app from the Apple App Store.
2. Or just fork out the money and buy a house in the United States.